# iOS / objective-c(++) equivalent to Windows I/O Completion Ports?

Tags: ios, objective-c, .net, objective-c++, io-completion-ports

Suppose I want to implement a method that loads a file asynchronously and returns some task with the file's content as its result. In .NET, I could say:

```
public async Task<byte[]> GetFileContentsAsync(string path)
{
  using (var fs = File.OpenRead(path))
  using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
  { 
      await fs.CopyToAsync(ms);
      return ms.ToArray();
  }
}
```

Under the covers, `CopyToAsync` will utilize IO completion ports to ensure that a thread won't be wasted idling, waiting for IO.

Is there an equivalent in Objective-C(++)? Can I implement the following contract efficiently?

```
ppl::task<StorageBufferPtr> GetFileContentsAsync(const shared_ptr<string> path) 
{    
    ??? 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you are looking for is here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/TechniquesforReadingandWritingCustomFiles/TechniquesforReadingandWritingCustomFiles.html

Comment: So Windows *I/O completion ports* ~= iOS *dispatch I/O* and I need to use the GCD, specifically `dispatch_read` / 'dispatch_write' in most cases. Got it, thanks!